# Apex Column Style

Tags: apex

I am attempting to center the contents of a column value which I am placing in a datatable's. I can't find an attribute for the datatable which can do this.

I have used style attribute in apex:column as style="text-align=center" but its not working.

Any clue to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS uses a `key: value;` syntax; in your code, you wrote `key=value`, which is not valid CSS. You must exactly follow this syntax to achieve your desired results. Here's a copy-paste example for you:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="records">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!records}" var="rec" rows="10">
        <apex:column style="text-align: center;" value="{!rec.Name}" />
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:page>
```